# Does $\iint_D \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} dx dy $ converge on $D= \left\{ (x, y) : x^2+y^2\leq ax \right\} $ ? If yes, what value does it converge to?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral, conditional-convergence

Powers equal to $2$ entice the polar substitution.

$D= \left\{ (x, y) : x^2+y^2\leq ax \right\}$, so $0 \leq r \leq a \cos \phi.$ For the domain to make sense, we need either $\phi \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}] \cup [\frac{3 \pi}{2}, 2\pi)$ and $a \geq 0$, or $\phi \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2}]$ and $a \leq 0$.

Everything below was achieved with help from the comments.

$$\iint_D \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} dx dy = \iint_{D'} r \cos^2 \phi \ d\phi dr.$$

Case $1$:

Since $(0, 0) \in D $ (equivalently, $r=0$ for any $\phi$) makes the integrand indefinite,

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^2 \phi \ d \phi 
\int_{\epsilon}^{a \cos \phi} r \ dr 
+ 
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
\int_{\frac{3 \pi}{2}}^{2\pi} \cos^2 \phi \ d \phi 
\int_{\epsilon}^{a \cos \phi} r \ dr
$$

$$
2\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^2 \phi \ d \phi 
\int_{\epsilon}^{a \cos \phi} r \ dr 
$$

$$
2\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \frac{a^2 \cos^2 \phi}{2}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \right) \cos^2 \phi \ d \phi 
$$

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( {a^2 \cos^2 \phi}-{\epsilon^2} \right) \cos^2 \phi \ d \phi 
$$

Put $0$ instead of $\epsilon$, because it won't let me integrate:
$$
a^2
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} { \cos^4 \phi} \ d \phi = \frac{a^2}{2} Β \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{2} \right) = \frac{a^2}{2} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{5}{2})}{\Gamma(3)} = \frac{a^2}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot 0.75 \sqrt{\pi}}{2} = \frac{3 a^2 \pi}{16}
$$

For case $2$, the result should be same.

Was this correct?

Formula $Β(m, n)=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2m-1} \theta \cos^{2n-1} \theta \ d \theta$ was used, but I'm not sure I can extract it myself, and would be grateful for reference.

The answer would be, that for fixed $a$, it's convergent. (I am not sure about the definition of convergence here, and can't look it up, since the classes were missed, and google is blocked).

---

For Oliver Jones:

let $r_i=a\frac{i}{i+1}$, $\phi_i=\frac{\delta}{i}.$

$$\iint_{D_\delta} r \cos^2 \phi \ d\phi dr= \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \sum_i \left(a\frac{i}{i+1}\right) \left(\cos^2 \frac{\delta}{i} \right) 
\left( 
a\frac{i+1}{i+2} - a\frac{i}{i+2}
\right) 
\left( 
\frac{\delta}{i+1}-\frac{\delta}{i}
\right) =
\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \sum_i \left(a\frac{i}{i+1}\right) \left(1 \right) 
\left( 
\frac{a}{(i+1)(i+2)}
\right) 
\left( 
\frac{-\delta}{i(i+1)}
\right)
=
 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(a^2\frac{1}{i+1}\right) \left(1 \right) 
\left( 
\frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)}
\right) 
\left( 
\frac{-\delta}{(i+1)}
\right).
$$

It converges because of the $4$th power in the denominator.

Or maybe like this:

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\epsilon}^a x \ dx \int_{-\sqrt{x(a-x)}}^{\sqrt{x(a-x)}} \frac{1}{1+ (y/x)^2} d (y/x)$$

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\epsilon}^a 2 x \arctan \sqrt{x(a-x)} \ dx  $$

How to proceed here, I am not sure.

---

$$
\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}\iint_{\delta^2 \leq r^2+ar \cos \theta + a^2/4 \leq a^2/4} r \cos ^2 \theta \ dr \ d\theta
$$

Let's choose $\theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2], a\geq 0$.

Then 
$
\delta^2 \leq r^2 - ar + a^2/4 \leq  r^2+ar \cos \theta + a^2/4 \leq r^2 + a^2/4 \leq a^2/4.
$
$
0 \leq r^2 - ar + a^2/4 -\delta^2 \Longrightarrow r\in (0, \frac{a-2\delta}{2}).
$

$$
\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos ^2 \theta \ d \theta \int_0^{(a-2\delta)/2} r dr = \frac{a^2}{8} В(1/2, 3/2) = \frac{a^2 \pi}{16}
$$

Comment: You have $(0,0)\in D$ and the integrand isn't defined there. How are improper double integrals defined?

Comment: @OliverJones $ \int \int_D f (x, y) \ dx dy = \lim_{\delta x_i, \delta y_j \rightarrow 0} \Sigma_i \Sigma_j f(x_i, y_j) \delta x_i \delta x_j$ by definition; on practice usually $\int_a^b \ dx \ \int_{y_1(x)}^{y_2(x)} \ f(x, y) \ dy$.

Comment: Just as an alternative way of thinking, suppose $a\ge 0$. Notice that if $x^{2}+y^{2}\le ax$ then $x^{2}-ax +y^{2}\le 0$ so that, completing squares, we have $(x-a/2)^{2}+y^{2}\le a^{2}/4$. This is a circle translated with radius $a/2$. You could use the change of variables $x = rcos\phi +1/2$. Doesn't it simplify your analyses?

Comment: @Willy.K Thank you, I am trying this out right now. Also, I am sorry, but shouldn't it be $x=r \cos \phi + a/2$?

Comment: Yes, it should. I  mistakenly typed it $1/2$.

Comment: shouldn't the integrand be $r\cos^2 \theta$ after converting to polar?

Comment: @DougM thank you, I'll fix it now.

Comment: For what it's worth, the integral has a value of $\frac{3a^2\pi}{16}$ (according to computation in *Mathematica*)

Comment: @user170231 That's what I got by hand too.

Comment: @fragileradius This is an improper integral which is defined in a way similar to the one variable case. Let $D_\delta$ be $D$ with a wedge with angle $\delta$  cut out that misses the origin.Then decide on the convergence of $\displaystyle{\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}  \iint _{D_\delta}  \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\, dA   }$.

Comment: @OliverJones I am not sure if I understood you (sorry, English as a second language), did you mean a slim slice of a circle, or the circle without a slim slice? Either way, I included two interpretations of what (I assume) you offered to do with this problem in the post. Thank you.

Comment: @fragileradius I mean remove a sector (slice of the circle). There is no need for the $i$'s in your answer. Just convert to polar coordinates and adjust the $\theta$ limits accordingly.

Comment: @fragileradius Actually, thinking about it some more, it might be easier to remove a circle of radius $\delta$ centered at the origin and then switch to polars. It will still be a little messy, though.

Comment: @fragileradius Your above calculations are incorrect; you can't split the integrals when the limits depend on functions.

Comment: @OliverJones I've tried to to remove a circle of radius $\delta$ centered at the origin and then switch to polars.

Comment: @fragileradius Your method of proof isn't correct. As I said, you can't split the integrals in that way. Also, the limits in the outer integral should involve $\delta$.

Comment: The integrand $f$ is bounded (besides, the set of discontinuities of $f$ and the boundary of $D$ have content zero), so the integral exists as the limit of Riemann sums, you do not have to define it as an improper integral. Further, you can apply a change of variables and then evaluate the double integral as an iterated integral (provided that the inner integral exists). Thus you just need to consider the case $a > 0$ and evaluate
$$2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{a \cos t} r \cos^2 t \, dr dt$$
by using the identity
$$\cos^4 t = \frac 3 8 + \frac 1 2 \cos 2 t + \frac 1 8 \cos 4 t.$$

Comment: @Maxim Yes, your approach is much simpler. You're using Fubini's theorem for improper integrals, which is permitted since the integrand is nonnegative on $D$.

Comment: @OliverJones You do not have to introduce the notion of an improper integral at all. Also, the conditions that I listed are sufficient: if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $D$ and $F(v) = \int_a^b f(u, v) du$ exists for all $v$, then $\int_c^d F(v) dv$ also exists and is equal to the double integral. $f$ does not have to be nonnegative.

Comment: @Maxim Right. I forgot $f$ is bounded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same result as your first one. But I don't see the need for special functions, or introducing the $\epsilon$ you use.

Consider the region $x^2+y^2\leq ax$. This is the same as $$\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+y^2\leq\frac{a^2}{4}$$

So the region is a disc centered at $\left(\frac{a}{2},0\right)$ with its boundary touching the origin. I'll assume $a>0$. A disc like this is described in polar coordinates by $r\leq a\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

So the integral is 
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{r=a\cos(\theta)}r\cos^2(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2}\cos^2(\theta)\int_{r=0}^{r=a\cos(\theta)}r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2}\cos^2(\theta)\frac{1}{2}a^2\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2}\cos^4(\theta)\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\theta=\pi/2}\left(\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}\right)^2\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{\varphi=-\pi}^{\varphi=\pi}\left(\frac{1+\cos(\varphi)}{2}\right)^2\,d\varphi\\
&=\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{\varphi=-\pi}^{\varphi=\pi}\left(\frac14+\cos(\varphi)+\frac{1}{4}\cos^2(\varphi)\right)\,d\varphi\\
&=\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{\varphi=-\pi}^{\varphi=\pi}\left(\frac14+\frac{1}{4}\cos^2(\varphi)\right)\,d\varphi\\
&=\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{\varphi=-\pi}^{\varphi=\pi}\left(\frac14+\frac{1}{8}\left(1+\cos(2\varphi)\right)\right)\,d\varphi\\
&=\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{\varphi=-\pi}^{\varphi=\pi}\left(\frac38+\frac{1}{8}\cos(2\varphi)\right)\,d\varphi\\
&=\frac{a^2}{4}\int_{\varphi=-\pi}^{\varphi=\pi}\frac38\,d\varphi\\
&=\frac{3a^2}{32}(2\pi)=\frac{3a^2\pi}{16}
\end{align}$$